# AWS lambda with JSON input

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gson

I'm trying to convert InputStream to JSON and parse it to POJO object. But there pojo is always an empty object. Do you see any issue with my method? I'm using AWS lambda with function URL. Is there a better way to create a REST API in AWS lambda?

```
public class MyHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

private final Gson gson = new Gson();

@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {

    // reading json input
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    Request request = gson.fromJson(reader, Request.class);

    // getting logger
    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

    // logging input
    logger.log(request.toString());

    Response response = new Response(999);

    // creating response
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    writer.write(gson.toJson(response));
    writer.close();
   }
}


public class Request {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Request() {
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Request{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
   }
 }
```

Comment: How are you supplying the name on the request when you invoke the function URL? Do you know for sure that the custom serialization variant of the Lambda function RequestHandler is actually supported for function URL invocation (vs. regular Lambda function invocation)?

Comment: AFAIK it should work this way. I'm sending the request from postman and have it set to JSON for request body.

Comment: Could the problem be as simple as the fact that your `Request` POJO doesn't have a usable, non-default constructor or setName method?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty object"? Is the `logging.log` call executed and is the result `Request{name=''}`? For debugging you could first read the request to a String and log that as well to see what you are actually receiving before passing it to Gson. Not sure if that is relevant here, but in case you are using ProGuard or R8 or similar you also have to configure them to not remove fields from your classes or rename the fields.

Comment: As side note: When constructing the `InputStreamReader` you should also explicitly specify `UTF_8` as charset. And instead of `writer.write(gson.toJson(...))` you can directly call `gson.toJson(..., writer)`.